# Chrome has a feature that closes alert boxes on the release of space-bar. How can I create an alert box that stays open on the release of space-bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For example. I'd like to open an alert when space-bar is pressed. But chrome closes the box onkeyup of spacebar.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  var key_code = event.keyCode;

  if(key_code == "32") {
     alert("Space-bar was pressed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use document.onkeyup instead

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  var key_code = event.keyCode;

  if(key_code == "32") {
     alert("Space-bar was pressed");
  }
}
```